# Confused by "comes down to" and similar phrases

Tags: phrases

I'm confused by the following sentence, which I encountered under the entry for *advantage* in Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English:

> *When it comes down to working from home, you have to decide if the advantages outweigh the disadvantages.*

Can someone explain what it means?

I'm confused because in my understanding of English, the phrases "*when it comes to*", "*come to*", "*come down to*", and "*when it comes down to it/that*" all have different meanings, and I'm not sure which is being applied in this sentence.

It would help me understanding of you could provide other examples based on "*when it comes down to doing something …*" .

Comment: I suspect the composer of the troublesome sentence has confused these idioms you list, and written "comes down to" when "comes to" was meant.

Comment: Yes, it is an error. The sentence should be, “When it comes to working from home..."

Comment: P.S. Could you change "pharases" in your title to "phrases" - Thanks.

Comment: "And when it comes down to having the choice of being right or protecting you, I'll be wrong every single time." From the TV show *South of Nowhere,* per [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0821636/quotes). I had to flip through several pages of Google hits on "when it comes down to" before coming to the first one where a gerund followed. And that's dialogue written for a teenage character, hardly a gold standard.

Comment: When it comes down to eating more vegetables in order to live longer, I guess I'm going to die young.

Comment: @Ehsan - Please give a link to the dictionary entry.

Comment: I dont know whats your mind ? but I write a part of it to you : the advantages and disadvantages of something  :  the advantages and disadvantages of living in a big city .     the advantages outweigh the disadvantages (=the advantages are more valuable) When it comes down to working from home, you have to decide if the advantages outweigh the disadvantages.

Comment: I must thank Mkennedy because you edit my question well .
It is your kindness .
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

When I say "... it comes down to ..." I am usually introducing a concluding remark, a conclusion, a summary of a preceding longer discussion. When I say "It comes to ..." I am introducing a step along the road or the argument. The insertion of the word "down" suggests a metaphor that parallels "boiling down", reducing, condensing, or similar notions. I therefore disagree with donovan and chasly, both of whom take amore limited view and regard "comes down to" as wrong.

Comment: - I don't disagree with your analysis. I just don't think it applies to the specific sentence given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with the expression:  "when it comes down to the wire...."

"down to the wire

To the last minute; to the very end. For example, We're just about down to the wire with this project. This term comes from horseracing, where it was long the practice to stretch a wire across and above the track at the finish line. It was extended to figurative use about 1900."  Free Dictionary, Idioms